# The meaning of the word "immediately"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning

I saw this in a post:

> ...it is okay or at least not immediately wrong.

What does immediately mean in this context? Although I have looked up this word in several dictionaries, its use in this context still remains vague to me. I really do need clarification on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context the meaning is that it is not `immediately apparent` that it is wrong.

To give a usage example, if you're substituting an ingredient while cooking and you feel like it worked, but the recipe isn't done yet, you could say that "It worked out, or at least isn't immediately wrong"

Comment: OK, thanks! That means apparent is not stated there. Hmm, now I get.